# use css to do conditional hide and show

Tags: html, css

I have the following html block.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="prospective_tenant_wrap">
    <p class="hint">Prospective tenant</p>
    <h2 class="title truncate">Puma</h2><span class="unread">unread</span>
    <p class="tenant_category">Bags &amp; Leather Goods</p>
  </div>
  <div class="agency_wrap">
    <p class="hint">Event Agency</p>
    <h2 class="title truncate">Cyclops Group</h2><span class="unread">unread</span></div>
</div>
```

In my list, there's a case where .prospective_tenant_wrap or .agency_wrap will disappear. How to show only ONE .unread if that's the case using css? Says I don't want to alter the looping logic using my template engine?

Comment: use the `.prospective_tenant_wrap.unread` css class? (both prospective tenant and unread)  I assume you're using JavaScript

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? The answer to the question as it stands now is "you don't need to, because if you hide one ...wrap, the "unread" will be hidden with it" and I'm not sure you meant that.

Comment: @MrLister show one badge of unread, but as you can see in the tag, it appears to have 2. If I do .unread:first-child{ display:none } it doesn't work because one among them are optional, you get it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without altering your looping logic. Normally you could use selectors like `:last-child`, `nth-child`, etc. (but I would recommend against it, since changing markup breaks your CSS).

Why don't you want to change the loop logic? Conditionally hiding/showing would be much easier when you could set classes like "unread--first" or "unread--last", etc. and style accordingly.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you only ever want to show one "unread", right? I.E. if both "_wrap"s are visible, show only the first one? In that case, the question is, how will the css know which of the "_wrap"s are hidden and which are visible.